# Views News slider

Tags: 7, views, ajax, javascript

I have this design:

[image]

E.G. Click "Structure" header, open contents and come img.

Created content type and installed Views. Seperate image, header, content fields via block.

[image]

Like our design but site now static. I want dynamic structure but i don't know. Well, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can able to do it using "[Views Module](http://drupal.org/project/views)" and "[Views Slideshow Module](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)" . Below Steps may help you.

- Create a Content Type.
- Add all necessary fields.
- Create content
- Create a view that lists all above content and use views field option to display above content type fields.
- Select the Views Style as "Views Slideshow".
- Configure settings and select pager as title field.
- That's it ! With little bit of CSS and Positioning you are good to go :-)